# How to cache search results retrieved from auto-complete API

Tags: java, gwt, autocomplete, jsonp, bootstrap-typeahead

I've been working on a searching auto-complete feature with [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) ,[GWT](http://dawa.aws.dk/dok/api) and data comes from http://dawa.aws.dk/dok/api by JsonP request..

**The Typahead creation method is below**

```
private Typeahead<Location> createTypeAhead() {
    typeAhead = new Typeahead<>(new Dataset<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void findMatches(final String query, final SuggestionCallback<Location> callback) {
            requestCounter--;
            startSendingRequest = true;
            clear.setIcon(IconType.SPINNER);
            clear.setIconSpin(true);
            final Set<Suggestion<Location>> suggestions = new HashSet<>();
            queryLower = query.toLowerCase();
            JsonpRequestBuilder jsonpRequestBuilder;
            if (!streetSelected) {
                jsonpRequestBuilder = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
                jsonpRequestBuilder.requestObject("https://dawa.aws.dk/vejnavne/autocomplete?side=1&per_side=500&noformat=1&q=" + queryLower + "*", new AsyncCallback<MyJsArray<VejAutocomplete>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Notify.notify("suggestion matches failed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(MyJsArray<VejAutocomplete> result) {
                        Set<Location> locationSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                        for (VejAutocomplete item : result.getAsList()) {
                            String lowerCase = item.getTekst().toLowerCase();
                            if (lowerCase.startsWith(queryLower)) {
                                locationSet.add(new Location(Location.LocationType.STREET, item.getTekst(), item));
                                locationArrayList.clear();
                                locationArrayList.addAll(locationSet);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            for (Location address : locationArrayList) {
                String value = address.getValue();
                Suggestion<Location> s = Suggestion.create(value, address, this);

                if (address.getValue().toLowerCase().startsWith(queryLower)) {
                    suggestions.add(s);
                }
            }
            callback.execute(suggestions);
            if (typeAhead.getValue().length() != 0 && queryLower.length() <= 5 && requestCounter < 5 && requestCounter > 0) {

                new Timer() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        findMatches(queryLower, callback);
                    }
                }.schedule(500);
            } else {
                clear.setIconSpin(false);
                clear.setIcon(IconType.CLOSE);
                requestCounter = 5;
            }
        }
    });
    return typeAhead;
}
```

**The result is like below:**

[image]

I used recursion to send 4-5 times of request because it's not showing the suggestion list with the keyword of single letter. And It still won't work with some single letters like "s" or "e". Data successfully retrieved from the API but doesn't show in the suggestion list like below:

[image]

I assume that I should cache all search results then recreate the auto-complete from scratch, it becomes complicated in that case.

Any good idea to solve this problem?